# How to convert c# arrays to JSON with one array item propety value set as reference to item from another

Tags: c#, javascript, json, angularjs, json.net

To properly bind Java script arrays to AngularJs view I need them look like:

```
   var ingridients = [
       {name: 'Vodka'},
       {name: 'Gin'},
       {name: 'Rum'}
    ];

    var drinks = [
       {name: 'Bloody Mary', basicIngridient: ingridients[0]},
       {name: 'Gin & Tonic', basicIngridient: ingridients[1]},
       {name: 'Daiquiry', basicIngridient: ingridients[2]}
    ];
```

Suppose I have c# arrays like:

```
    class Drink
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Ingridient BasicIngridient { get; set; }
        }

    class Ingridient
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

    static Ingridient[] ingridients = new Ingridient[] 
        { 
            new Ingridient { Name = "Vodka" },
            new Ingridient { Name = "Gin" },
            new Ingridient { Name = "Rum"}
        };

    Drink[] drinks = new Drink[]
        {
            new Drink{ Name = "Bloody Mary", BasicIngridient = ingridients[0]},
            new Drink{ Name = "Gin & Tonic", BasicIngridient = ingridients[1]},
            new Drink{ Name = "Daiquiri", BasicIngridient = ingridients[2]}
        };
```

The question is: How could I convert these C# arrays to get needed JSON arrays?
I know about JSON. Net library but I didn't manage to find the solution in docs.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [javascripserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class

```
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(drinks);
 Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't consider array indexes the result JSON will be:`[{"Name":"Bloody Mary","BasicIngidient":{"Name":"Vodka"}}, etc.` but I need it: `[{"Name":"Bloody Mary","BasicIngidient":ingridients[0]}, etc.`

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you want it to work with references, not values? Json.NET has [PreserveReferencesHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm), more [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm), which is *sort of* what you're describing, but not exactly. I don't think you can do exactly what you're describing.

Comment: @WhiteKnight [JSON](http://json.org/) does not support references like that. It's just a data format; not code. The closest you can get is outputting a String of code `"BasicIngidient": "ingridients[0]"`, which you will then have to parse/evaluate yourself after `JSON.parse()`. Or, set the property to the index alone, `basicIngridient: 0`, and reference `ingridients[this.basicIngridient]` later.

Comment: @WhiteKnight I didn't notice the array indexes you required. As JonathanLonowski said, JSON isn't code.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski Thanks, it seems I didn't understand the main transport role of JSON. The question is closed;