# create array data in json with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create the following JSON data:

```
var data = [[1, 27], [2, 34], [3, 51], [4, 48], [5, 55], [6, 65], [7,
          61], [8, 70], [9, 65], [10, 75], [11, 57], [12, 59], [13, 62]];
```

I already try but manually use string builder but I know it is not a good solution, then I create some merge something like this

```
  var bldgNum = new int[] { 1, 2, 5 };
  var flatNum = new int[] { 27, 109, 25, 200 };
  var address = bldgNum
                .Zip(flatNum, (bl, fl) => "[" + bl + ", " + fl.ToString() + "]");
```

perhaps anyone have a better solution for doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert c# arrays to JSON with one array item propety value set as reference to item from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953335/how-to-convert-c-sharp-arrays-to-json-with-one-array-item-propety-value-set-as-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create JSON string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056121/how-to-create-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array of arrays, and use `JavaScriptSerializer` to produce a string:

```
// This creates an array of two-element arrays:
var address = bldgNum
    .Zip(flatNum, (bl, fl) => new[] {bl, fl})
    .ToArray();
// This produces a JSON string that corresponds to your array-of-arrays:
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var str = jss.Serialize(address);
```

Comment: nice, thanks for the enlightment, so basically my solution is create an array lets say an array a and array b, then create an array of two-element arrays like you write in the answer then I convert not in JavaScriptSerializer() but I do convert in JsonConvert.SerializeObject(address);

Comment: @awancilik That's right, `JsonConvert` works very well, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Newtonsoft.Json library (you can get it from NuGet). For your example something like this should solve your problem.

```
var result = new List<int[]> {new[] {1, 27}, new[] {2, 34}, new int[] {3, 51}};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```